# Blender not showing tool bar

Tags: modeling

I'm using Kali Linux and i had a great time with blender last few months. But suddenly now it is not showing many important stuff like tool bar and menu bars. Is there anything to do with this. I am suspecting my last update but not sure.
Current View
[image]

Comment: Please state what version of Blender you are using

Comment: It's 2.79 . Could you please tell me a solution. I tried to reset it using "reset factory settings". But not worked. It doesn't find the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't see the menu try resetting blender to its default layout by pressing  <kbd>Space</kbd>  then typing "Load Factory Settings". Select the displayed option and the interface should go back to default.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't find the command you specified.

Comment: updated the answer. It should be "Load Factory Settings"

Comment: didn't work. It appear the command correctly but it does not change anything for me after execute that command.

Comment: Are you using blender installed from your systems repo or from Blender.org/download?

Comment: from the system repo

Comment: i uninstalled it and installed it again by apt-get remove and apt-get install but it appears same. Im really suffering

Comment: Try using the blender version from https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: Thanks. That downloaded version worked. But it is not a install version, it just click and run version. I'm curious to know what happened with the installed one. Anyway thanks.